# "Legendre-type" integrals involving $\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-2t\cos(\theta)+1}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, legendre-polynomials, beta-function

Summing Legendre polynomials $P_{l}(\cos\theta)$ often leads to expressions containing $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2t\cos\theta+1}}$, as this is the generating function for the Legendre polynomials. I want to evaluate the following integral:
\begin{equation}
I(\gamma,s,\theta,\lambda)=\int_0^1dt\frac{t^{s+i\gamma}(1-t)^{-2i\gamma+1}}{\sqrt{(e^{i\lambda}t)^2-2(te^{i\lambda})\cos\theta+1}}
\end{equation}

which arose from summing Legendre polynomials. Is there a general approach for handling integrals of this kind? Is there any specific reference I should consult?

All parameters are $\gamma,s,\theta,\lambda$ are assumed to be in a region where this integral converges.

Comment: Its a "four-marked points integral" so it an the Appell F_1 function.